# Applying regex in Openrefine with Python

Tags: python, regex, jython, openrefine, grel

I am trying to use the `value.findall()` function in OpenRefine 3.4 by finding all the rows in a column that contain specific strings i.e., "`WASHER`", "`FLAT`", "`10MM`" and "`SS`"`  in any random order given and return that into a new column. Here is a snippet of my codes.

```
import re
regex=r"(\WASHER)(\"FLAT")(\"10MM")(\"SS")"
return re.findall(regex, value)
```

Here is what am what screen looks like.

[image: screenshot of my what my the data in the column looks like]

Comment: How about "(WASHER|FLAT|10MM|SS)" for the regex?

Comment: I finally managed by using an if statement to check all the necessary conditions

Comment: Please let know if the approach below helped you, and if yes, consider accepting (clicking the gray mark on the left).

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the following code into the box:

```
import re
regex=r'^(?=.*\bWASHER\b)(?=.*\bFLAT\b)(?=.*\b10MM\b)(?=.*\bSS\b).*'
return re.findall(regex, value)
```

This will return a whole string that contains `WASHER`, `FLAT`, `10MM` and `SS` as whole words anywhere in the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOHpmh/1).

If they occur in immediate succession, you can use

```
regex=r'.*?\bWASHER\s+FLAT\s+10MM\s+SS\b.*'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOHpmh/2).